# What is the advantage of taking monochrome photographs in standard lenses

Tags: amateur-observing, light

I've readen "When photographing faint objects monochrome photos will resolve more than RGB pics"
Is this really a thing? If yes, how?

Comment: In the olden days, the "pixels" on black and white film were smaller than the "pixels" on color film. Therefore, for a given film speed (eg, ASA1600 or ASA 3200), black and white film can resolve objects better. ... I think (someone should doublecheck this). I also think ASA3200 film was black and white only (no color version), but, again, could be wrong.

Comment: Twofold: (1) monochrome sensors do not have Bayer patterns, so higher spatial resolution under diffraction limited means better ability to resolve objects. (2) monochrome sensors do not have visible color filters and hence much higher quantum efficiency, for faint objects tiny light irradiance matters.